# Shift symmetry and vacuum expectation values

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, field-theory

I have come across theories with a Nambu-Goldstone boson $\phi$ originating from a broken $U(1)$ symmetry where there is a leftover shift symmetry $\phi \rightarrow \phi + \alpha$ (and possibly other fields transforming in a way parametrised by $\alpha $). Now, what this really means is that I can substitute $\phi = \tilde{\phi} +\alpha$ and the functional form of the Lagrangian remains the same (finally relabelling $\tilde{\phi} \rightarrow \phi$).
However, In QFT, is it not true that the proper fields to work with should satisfy $\langle \phi\rangle =0$? But if I start with such a field, upon acting with the global 'shift transformation' I now have $\langle\tilde{\phi}\rangle=\alpha \neq 0$.

Why is this not a problem?

Comment: why do you think that in QFT $<\phi>=0$? What about the Standard Model Higgs VEV for example?

Comment: It is my impression that whenever $<\phi>=\alpha \neq 0$ we redefine $\phi = \alpha + \tilde{\phi}$ and then work with this new field $\tilde{\phi}$ and say this is the proper d.o.f.. Same thing happens for the Higgs field in the SM.

Comment: then, after the shift you can redefine phi again, $\phi'=\tilde{\phi}-\alpha$. Its VEV will then vanish.

Comment: You could ask the same question about any symmetry that is spontaneously broken. Spontaneous symmetry breaking means that there are degenerate vacua that are connected by the broken symmetry transformations. For compact symmetry groups, it is more common to picture this using a Maxican-hat potential where all the different vacua have nonzero $\langle\phi\rangle$, only differing by a phase of the order parameter. But the principle is the same.

Comment: In a theory with a shift symmetry, $\phi\to\phi+\alpha$ -- which is not U(1) but R -- you will analogously have degenerate vacua, differing by the value of $\langle\phi\rangle$. There is nothing special about the choice of $\langle\phi\rangle=0$. All such vacua are physically equivalent.